# Export Geo-spatial Data from SQL Server to ArcGIS?

Tags: geocoding, arcgis

I'm not too familiar with ArcGIS, but is it possible to export geo-spatial data from SQL Server in a format that can easily be imported by ArcGIS?  Is there a proprietary format for ArcGIS?

I'm not interested (I don't think) in purchasing ArcServer,  I just want my data exposed (via web services) a client who does use Arc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using  ArcMap 10.0 version, then use the  Query Layer feature to add SQL Server Spatial table data into ArcMap 10.
Use "File->Add Data-> Add Query Layer.." interface.
Using this You can connect to a SQL Server spatial tables and add them into ArcMap. Once you added into ArcMap, You can convert these data into Shape file format (a generally used GIS data files for ESRI ArcGIS tools). There are certain limitation with this method.

Another way is use ogr2ogr tool 
see the link for more details

http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/09/29/exporting-spatial-data-from-sql-server-to-esri-shapefile/